Can I still use iTunes instead of music on Windows?
The music tab is gone for me in iTunes, and I am being forced to use apple music on windows.

Is there any way to make "music" reappear in iTunes so that I can use iTunes to listen to apple music?


In macOS Music View-as Songs can be configured top be like the iTunes interface - together with View Show Column browser - perhaps this is also so under Windows - however it is not under iOS
